# Why does the variable "bmi" only get the value of the variable "weight"?

Tags: java

```
public class P2A7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = args[0];
        int weight = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        double length = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
        double bmi = weight / length * length;
        System.out.println(bmi);
    }
}
```

Passing `java Name 80 1.9` from the command line gives the output "80".
Why are the division and multiplication completely ignored?

Putting parentheses around "length * length" fixes this.

Comment: Dividing by a number and then multiplying by that same number gets you back to the initial number. This is just how math works.

Comment: Because you divide by something and then immediately multiply by it again. `/` and `*` have equal precedence, so `weight / length * length` means `(weight / length) * length`.

Comment: I mixed this up with assignments. Assignments on the same row (e.g. x = y += z = 1;) get done from right to left and other binary operations get done from left to right (e.g. 5 % 2 * 3 / 6). Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kristjan Link, This is because precedence of operator, when you write `weight / (length * length)` you increase precedence of multiplication `*`,  because precedence of operator inside parentheses is always more than operator outside parentheses

Use of parentheses fix it because it increases precedence of `*` operator. By using parentheses you explicitly give `*` more precedence than `/` that's why multiplication expression will be executed first due to its increased precedence other wise both `*` and `/` have same precedence.

**NOTE:**

but remember despite same precedence `/` execute first than `*` because it comes first. Just like  `()` is way to increase precedence, shifting position of operator is another way increase or decrease precedence of operators.The table present [here](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html). will be helpful for you in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Because **double bmi = weight / length * length = weight** is **not same** as
 **double bmi= weight / (length * length)**

In the first case, You are ending up getting the same result as you are not using any parenthesis.

`/` and `*` have equal precedence, so `weight / length * length` means `(weight / length) * length`

Answer (score 0):

Because / has higher precedence than *. Hence, your code just performs divide and multiply by length which returns weight. () has higher precedence than / and hence the code inside () will execute first which results in weight multiplied by length*length